# Load-testing asp.net site (postbacks/viewstate)

Tags: asp.net, viewstate, load-testing

What is the best way to load-test an application that relies heavily on posts with viewstate (same posts can't be sent twice, so a simple record / replay won't do)?

Can I generate the viewstate to be used in in the posts?

Answer (score 1):

The best (but expensive) solution is to use [Visual Studio Team Test Edition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts2008/products/bb933754.aspx). It allows you to create and run [load tests using .Net code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364082.aspx).  It is very robust and allows you to run the tests on a farm of servers and collect all of the performance metrics, etc.